# how to retrieve html file shown in FireFox new tab view

Tags: html, file, firefox, caching

When I open a new tab in Firefox, I see a html file that used to be on my server and I thought was lost due to overwriting. It's nowhere in my home folder. How do I get hold of it? I'm hesitating to click it because it may refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the page to open a menu and then click View Source Code.

Answer (score 0):

Hover over it with your mouse and see if it shows a path, or try editing to find a path to it. If this doesn't work, the best thing to do would to try clicking it and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

1. Goto about:cache?device=disk
2. Find the link and click on it.
3. Copy the file at the path specified in "file on disk."
4. If the file is gzipped rename it to zip and then unzip it.
5. Voila, you have your file.

You could also try about:cache?device=memory … files there are not gzipped.